# Fix div in position across screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS which puts autosearch results a `div`.

The problem I'm having is when you preview on a screen with a resolution equal to or lower than 1280 x 1024  it places the div where I want, but if previewed on a different screen with a resolution of 1680 x 1050 it places the search results on a different side of the page.

I was playing around the `left` side of the CSS and I changed it to match with a screen size 1680 x 1050 it placed it where I wanted but then on a screen size of 1280 x 1024 it places it somewhere else.

Is there a way I could rewrite it to make to fix where I want irrespective of screen resolution?

```css
body {
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}
.content{
  width:900px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#searchid
{

  width:500px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:14px;
}
#result
{
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px #CCC solid;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 54%;
  top: 45px;
}
.show
{
  padding:10px; 
  border-bottom:1px #999 dashed;
  font-size:15px; 
  height:50px;
  z-index:50;

}
.show:hover
{
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.image_new {
  float: none;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
}
.live {
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,auto);
}
```

```html
 <input name="search" type="text" class="search" id="searchid" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
 <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn-style" id="button" value="Search" />
```

Comment: Please do also provide the html markup for this and, for the ease of udnerstanding, also a link to a jsfiddler.

Comment: Where is "where I want"? We have no idea if you want it fixed to the side, always in the middle, always x-amount from the side, or some other more complex rule.

Answer (score 0):

in order to change the webpage based on Screen Resolution, you would have to use a 'liquid' layout, which means that instead of specifying pixel values, you would specify percentage values. This can be done by calculating how much of the screen you want each element to take up and enter the corresponding percentage value instead of the original pixel value.

Comment: i change the left to percentage wise but still not good results